Blender Transform Synchronization Issue: G + ESC not updating object location correctly. Blender limitations?
I'm developing a plugin for Blender. I've encountered an issue with transform updates when using the grab (G key) operation.
When I rapidly move an object with the G key and then immediately press ESC to cancel, the object's location doesn't seem to update inside the blender api to match what Blender shows until I click anywhere in the Blender viewport. This only happens with cancelled transforms (ESC) after rapid movement.
Current behavior:
Object is at position A in Blender.
Press G, move object quickly around screen.
Press ESC - object returns to position A in Blender.
Blender API did not report position A.
Only after clicking in Blender viewport it does update to position A.
I've tried multiple approaches:
Using depsgraph update handlers.
Modal timers at different frequencies.
Transform operator hooks.
Event handlers for ESC key.
Forcing view layer updates.
Multiple validation checks.
I'm wondering if somebody had the same problem. Or if there is some Blender API limitations that I should know. Or maybe I'm just overthinking and there is simple solution.

"I'm wondering if somebody had the same problem." That is not a problem, as far as I know that is how it is supposed to work. Temporary states like while transforming aren't stored or logged anywhere. The Blender API provides info about saved data.

@DuarteFarrajotaRamos I would consider that a complete answer, not just a comment. Why isn’t it?

Seemed to short and terse for an answer. Also I'm not entirely sure about it, since I havent actually tested it, just intuition
